# SpringBoot and ProtoBuf: How to make HTTP 400s more useful by adding error in the response body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

We are using `ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter` to parse JSON request body to protos in our REST endpoints:

```
  @Bean
  ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter(
        JsonFormat.parser(), JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields());
  }
```

In the request, say there is an enum, and if there is a typo in the value, example,

```
{
     "type": "ELEPHAANT"
}
```

I get back a `HTTP 400` response with an empty body, and the console has:

```
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - POST "/foo-search", parameters={}
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.foobar.MasterController#sample(SampleRequest)
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Could not resolve parameter [0] in public com.foobar.models.ResponseOuterClass$SampleResponse com.foobar.MasterController.Sample(com.foobar.models.SampleRequestOuterClass$SampleRequest): I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid enum value: ELEPHAANT for enum type: SampleRequest.Filter.Type
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Using @ExceptionHandler com.foobar.advice.ExceptionHandlerAdvice#handleException(Exception, WebRequest)
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - No match for [*/*], supported: []
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid enum value: ELEPHAANT for enum type: ObtSampleRequest.Filter.Type]
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

The issue is clear in the console log:

```
Invalid enum value: ELEPHAANT for enum type: ObtSampleRequest.Filter.Type
```

Can I somehow make the response body more useful by including the above information?

Answer (score 1):

You could come up with a @RestControllerAdvice

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
       return e.getMessage(); // or return a nice error object with the nested exception's msg
  }

}
```